# How to execute a python file in another python function?

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to write a function that I can use to execute other python files...

the expected behviour should be, using the function to import other modules so that importing these modules should automatically execute the script.

the function below is what I wrote

```
fp_a = 'C:..../'  # file path to each python file
results= []
def running(script,filepath):
    try:
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(start_time)
        sys.path.insert(0,filepath)
        import script
        results.append('%s Completed Started at'+ start_time +' Ended at ' + end_time %(script))
        end_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(end_time)
    except:
        results.append('Salary Failed')

running('fx_rates',fp_a)
```

Comment: I think you should use `subprocess` commands in python for **command prompt/terminal** command execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actully able to figure this out by using the importlib module

```
import datetime,sys,os
sys.path.insert(0,'some path')
import importlib as ip
results= []
def execution(fp, file):
    sys.path.insert(0,fp)
    start_time = now(2)
    im = ip.import_module(file)
    end_time = now(2)
    try:
        if  not im.error:
            results.append(file+' Job Completed! Started at '+ start_time +' Ended at ' + end_time)
            print(file+' Job Completed! Started at  '+ start_time +' Ended at ' + end_time )
        else:
            results.append(file+' Job Failed! Started at '+ start_time +' Failed at ' + end_time + ' The error was: '+ str(im.error))
            print(file+' Job Failed! Started at '+ start_time +' Failed at ' + end_time + ' The error was: '+ str(im.error))
    except:
            results.append(file+' Job Completed! Started at '+ start_time +' Ended at ' + end_time)
            print(file+' Job Completed! Started at  '+ start_time +' Ended at ' + end_time )
```